# How to run Source Code Scanner / Checkmarx against a Scratch Org?

Tags: scratch-org, checkmarx, security-scanner

Is it possible to run Source Code Scanner / Checkmarx against a Scratch Org?

When I click the Login link on this page:

https://security.secure.force.com/sourcescanner/

It redirects me to:

```
https://login.salesforce.com/services/auth/sso/00D30000000JsbiEAC/SourceScanner?site=https://security.secure.force.com/sourcescanner
```

And my `Scratch Org` login details don't work...

Is it possible to run Source Code Scanner / Checkmarx against a Scratch Org?

Comment: Pretty sure it is not possible. The scanner now explicitly lists orgs it can be used with, and I think they have to be developer edition.

Comment: can you try to copy URL and put test.salesforce.com or your scratch org domain (like cs*.salesforce.com)?

Comment: Changing it to `test.salesforce.com`  does not work...

Comment: Closest free option would be to run apex pmd locally for vscode

Comment: Or in IntelliJ IDEA. This is what we do during early prep for security review.

Comment: Is PMD results from VSVode a valid security check for the Salesforce security review team?

Comment: no, they are not

Comment: Apex PMD is recommended for pre-Security Review scans, but the actual Security Review needs a Checkmarx scan. I've not been in the ISV game since 2014, so you may want to contact Partner Support for the correct process for 2GMP. I do think it'd be worth keeping this question with an answer once you find out more information.

Comment: AFAIK no. FYI, this way of running scans https://forcedotcom.github.io/sfdx-scanner/ that is likely to flag some of the same issues that Checkmarx flags. Uses PMD and maintained by Salesforce.

Comment: Set of comments here looks like more of an blog article about how to prepare for a security review

Comment: Looking back at our most recent submission (just before the revamped UX for this), when we did the Checkmarx scan we actually selected a package version NOT an org. I.e. Checkmarx is not run against an org. Note, too, that test environments cannot be scratch orgs as it can literally take months for the review to be progressed.

Comment: @PhilW - running Checkmarx from a package version would be much easier. But no package versions appear in the list... have I authenticated against the wrong org? Which org should I use to authenticate?

Answer (score 1):

If you run your scan through the partner security portal, on https://security.secure.force.com/sourcescanner/PackageScannerMain, then you will find that you select package versions, not orgs, for the scan to run against.

Comment: Any ideas why the `Select Package Version ID to scan:` drop-down list is empty?

Comment: Is the package related to a listing? (Even a private one.)

Comment: I've added it to a listing, how long does it take to appear?

Comment: I can't say as I didn't try straight away. Is it working after the wait so far?